# ModelMetadata TemplateHint always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, modelmetadata, modelmetadataprovider

I am trying to create a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` to provide unobtrusive attributes for the JQuery UI Autocomplete widget.

I have a custom attribute that looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class AutocompleteAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.TemplateHint = "Autocomplete";
    }
}
```

and an editor template that looks like this:

```
@{
    var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"class", "text-box single-line"},
        {"autocomplete", "off"},
        {"data-autocomplete-url", "UrlPlaceholder" },
    };
}

@Html.TextBox("", ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, attributes)
```

I have a viewModel with a property of type `string` that includes the `AutocompleteAttribute` like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Autocomplete]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When I use this viewModel in my view I check the generated html and I am getting an `<input>` tag which has an attribute like this: `data-autocomplete-url="UrlPlaceholder"`.

What I want to do next is to be able to specify the URL in my view that uses my viewModel like this:

```
@model MyViewModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Create item"; }

@Html.AutoCompleteUrlFor(p => p.MyProperty, UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, "Autocomplete", "Home", null, Html.RouteCollection, Html.ViewContext.RequestContext, true))

// Other stuff here...

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

My `AutoCompleteForUrl` helper just saves the generated URL in a dictionary, using the property name as a key.

Next I have created a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` and registered it in global.asax using this line of code `ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomModelMetadataProvider();`.

What I want to do is to insert the URL to be used by the JQuery UI Autocomplete widget into the `metadata.AdditionalValues` dictionary to be consumed by the Autocomplete editor template.

My custom `ModelMetadataProvider` looks like this:

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<System.Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        if (metadata.TemplateHint == "Autocomplete")
        {
            string url;
            if(htmlHelpers.AutocompleteUrls.TryGetValue(metadata.propertyName, out url)
            {
                metadata.AdditionalValues["AutocompleteUrl"] = url;
            }
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

and my updated editor template looks like this:

```
@{
    object url;

    if (!ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.TryGetValue("AutocompleteUrl", out url))
    {
        url = "";
    }

    var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"class", "text-box single-line"},
        {"autocomplete", "off"},
        {"data-autocomplete-url", (string)url },
    };
}

@Html.TextBox("", ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, attributes)
```

The problem is, the `TemplateHint` property never equals "Autocomplete" in my custom model metadata provider so my logic to generate the URL never gets called. I would have thought that at this point the `TemplateHint` property would be set as I have called the base implementation of `CreateMetadata` of the `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`.

Here's what I can confirm:

- The `CustomModelMetadataProvider` is correctly registered as it contains other code which is getting called.
- The correct editor template is getting picked up as the Html that is generated contains an attribute called `"data-autocomplete-url"`.
- If I put a breakpoint in the Autocomplete template, Visual Studio goes to the debugger.

So can anyone shed any light on this for me please? What am I misunderstanding about the `ModelMetadataProvider` system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking through the ASP.NET MVC 3 source code I have discovered that the reason for this is because the `CreateMetadata` method is called prior to the `OnMetadataCreated` method of any `IMetadataAware` attributes that are applied to the model.

I have found an alternative solution that allows me to do what I wanted.

First of all I updated my `AutocompleteAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AutocompleteAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public const string Key = "autocomplete-url";
    internal static IDictionary<string, string> Urls { get; private set; }

    static AutocompleteAttribute()
    {
        Urls = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.TemplateHint = "Autocomplete";

        string url;

        if (Urls.TryGetValue(metadata.PropertyName, out url))
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues[Key] = url;
            Urls.Remove(metadata.PropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

and my Html helper method for setting the url in my views looks like this:

```
public static IHtmlString AutocompleteUrlFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        throw new ArgumentException("url");

    var property = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData).PropertyName;
    AutocompleteAttribute.Urls[property] = url;

    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

And then all I have to do in my editor template is this:

```
@{
    object url;
    ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.TryGetValue(AutocompleteAttribute.Key, out url);

    var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"class", "text-box single-line"},
        {"autocomplete", "off"},
        { "data-autocomplete-url", url },
    };
}

@Html.TextBox("", ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, attributes)
```